# Faceting (autocomplete) out of memory

Tags: solr, faceted-search

our solr crashes from time to time due to OutOfMemory error. We are stil on 4.0.0 version, but are planning to migrate to latest version after we solve following problem(s).

When I looked at tomcat log I see the following error:

```
SEVERE: null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$TermOrdValComparator.<init>(FieldComparator.java:1124)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SortField.getComparator(SortField.java:425)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueHitQueue$MultiComparatorsFieldValueHitQueue.<init>(FieldValueHitQueue.java:110)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueHitQueue.create(FieldValueHitQueue.java:173)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector.create(TopFieldCollector.java:1123)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:507)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:484)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:309)
    at si.amebis.termania.solr.ExternalSearch.search(ExternalSearch.java:307)
    at si.amebis.termania.solr.ExternalSearch.handleRequestBody(ExternalSearch.java:235)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1699)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:455)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:276)
    ... 12 more
```

just after the request for a autocomplete field (suggest as you type). Request details are below:

```
q - *:*
start - 0
rows - 0
fq - (Type:1 OR Type:2)
facet - true
facet.limit - 20
facet.mincount - 1
facet.sort - true
facet.prefix - "mi"
facet.field - "Autocomplete"
-- 
which returns 8105170 hits
```

where Autocomplete field is defined as:

```
<field name="Autocomplete" type="grams" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" required="False" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldtype name="grams" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="10" outputUnigrams="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

Index details:

```
Num document: 4338603
Index size: 10.1 Gb
Ram: 64Gb (-Xmx45000M)
Terms count in Autocomplete field: 70.459.723
```

I assume faceting on a text field and so many terms requires a lot of memory.

How can I calculate how much memory requires and is there any more efficient way to provide autocomplete (with phrases - n-grams)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect connect to the Solr instance to check where is the memory going? I'm guessing that is on the `FieldCache`, but is always good to check to be sure, Solr's faceting treats each field separately, so you should be able to check the memory consumption for that particular field. To estimate the memory usage for a facet query you could check this thread (http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-using-a-ridiculous-amount-of-memory-td4050840.html)

There is something also on your question you said that your query returns `8105170` hits, but your index has only `4338603` documents. Usually faceting on a text field is challenging because the number of terms could increase really fast, specially if you use shingles/ngrams.

Take a look at https://github.com/cominvent/autocomplete is a great starting point for an autocomplete feature backed by Solr (I've used this as my starting point for a few projects).

Depending on how have you implemented your autocomplete feature you could also try changing the `facet.method` (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting
) parameter and check if it helps.

Also take a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester.